# Добавление значений в LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList>

Tags: java, arraylist

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList> LHM = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList>();
```

Как добавлять элементы в `ArrayList`?

```
LHM.put(1, new ArrayList().add("1"));
```

Comment: добавьте ваше решение в вопрос

Comment: @mikhailvaysman Добавил строку которой я пытаюсь добавить элемент.

Comment: у вас в вопросе есть только формальное описание задачи - подобные вопросы обычно закрывают. добавьте свое решение или переформулируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить элемент можно следующим образом

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<>();

List<String> list = lhm.getOrDefault(1, new ArrayList<>());
list.add("1");
lhm.put(1, list);
```

Comment: Вы издевались))

Comment: этот сайт - сайт ответов на вопросы. я просто хотел, что бы вы четко задали вопрос. тогда ответ будет полезен не только вам, но и другим людям.

Comment: Так я кажется и задал. Есть lhm с определёнными типами и вопрос заключается в добавлении элементов в этот lhm. Можете предложить правку.

Comment: изначально ваш вопрос звучал иначе, но вы его исправили - за это спасибо.

Comment: Я сам не понял что написал)

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map
   .computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>())
   .add("value");
```

Этот вариант позволяет создавать объект только в случае, если это действительно требуется.